# How to check that Kafka is connected with ReactiveKafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, reactive-kafka

I work on a code that uses reactive-kafka module in Scala. My code uses lines such as:

```
val kafka = new ReactiveKafka()
kafka.consume(ConsumerProprties(...).readFromEndOfStream())
kafka.publish(ProducerProperties(...))
```

I have two questions:

1. I see that my code imports the package com.softwaremill.react.kafka. Can you give me a link to a detailed documentation? All information I found so far is too consice.
2. I want to check that the server is still connected to Kafka. How can I do it using com.softwaremill.react.kafka package?

Comment: ReactiveKafka is just a very small wrapper over official kafka client. Its source code is properly commented and is pretty easy to understand.

Comment: And there is no "detailed" documentation.

Comment: And just a hint to solve your problem. Create a new topic `heartbeat`. Create a consumer and producer stream for it. Whenever you want to check the connection, produce to `heartbeat` topic and check whether your consumer gets it.

Comment: Are you talking about this documentation: https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka ? 
What I see in this documentation is how to create a publisher and a subscriber, and not a consumer and a producer, as you said.

Comment: Well... that `Publisher` is a wrapper on top of `KafkaConsumer` which consumes messages from Kafka and publishes them downstream.  Similarly that `Subscriber` is a wrapper on top of `KafkaProducer` which consumes the subscribed streams and publishes messages to Kafka.

Comment: So... what is the difference between Consumer and Subscriber? Can I just create a Subscriber and treat it as if it were a Consumer?

Comment: Are you serious ? Do you mean to say that you are using ReactiveKafka without having any idea of what it does ? At least read the comment carefully.

Comment: I read the documentation: https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka and I found no anwer to my question. No, I don't know what ReactiveKafka actually does. That's why I posted this question. If you have any good resource/link you're more that welcome to post it.